# Painting artifacts of QGraphicsProxyWidget with QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

There was a problem of repainting the graphical scene when using elements with a QGraphicsProxyWidget with QPlainTextEdit.

It looks like this, as shown in the picture artifact_demo

[image]

The artifact is observed for Qt version 5.9.1 in Windows and Linux.
The minimal compiled example is posted on [github](https://github.com/kai66673/TestSceneFail)

Any ideas how to avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is setCacheMode of proxy widget to QGraphicsItem::DeviceCoordinateCache